# IntelliJ HTTP Client Is it possible to define constant global variables or shared environment variables

Tags: http, intellij-idea, client

I'm trying IntelliJ HTTP Client and I know that I can set environment variables and dynamic global variables in pre-request or post-request section. However is it possible to define some constant global variables or some shared environment variables I mean some variables which I can define and will be available in all my .http files and requests (like env variables) but which would be independent from specific chosen environment (or maybe is it possible to use two environments simultaneously).
I have few environments like DEV, STAGE, INTEGR, PERF env and also I have some common configuration which I don't want repeat in each env, but would like to have it in one place and easy modify, when I need.

Comment: This feature wasn't yet implemented. Please upvote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261193

Answer (score 1):

You may try jetbrain plugin [jetclient](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/21173-jetclient--the-ultimate-rest-client), which has `default` environment.

If you have to use IntelliJ HTTP Client, you can try this, kind of weird but it works:

- Create a http request and its [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#http-request-run-debug-configurations) [named](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#http_request_names) like `setGlobalEnv` with arbitrary request, like `GET https://httpbin.org/ip` in http request example.
- Edit [run configuration template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#templates), add new task before launch, run another configuration and choose `setGlobalEnv`.
- In `setGlobalEnv`, set global variables by `client.global.set("VariableName", "VariableValue")`. Then access varibale as `{{VariableName}}` in subsequent HTTP requests or using `client.global.get("VariableName")` in response handler scripts and pre-request scripts (refer to [client-properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-reference.html#client-properties)).